# Change Window Layout with GUILayout.Button in Unity & C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a menu in Unity using GUILayout buttons (and Begin/End Vertical/Horizontal, etc.) and I want it so that when I click a button, certain information displays below it. I'm trying to do it with this code:

foreach (Agent agent in agents)//(Agent agent in EntityManager.FindAll())
        {

```
    //GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    if (GUILayout.Button(agent.shortName))
    {
            Debug.Log("clicked" + agent.shortName);
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        GUILayout.Label("Health: "+agent.Health +"/"+agent.MaximumHealth);
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        GUILayout.Label("Thoughts: nothing");
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        /*if (agent.hasFlag)
        { //TODO: Add this function to agent
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            GUILayout.Label("Has the flag");        
            GUILayout.EndVertical();
        }*/
    }

        //GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.EndVertical();


    // Make the windows be draggable.
    GUI.DragWindow();
```

This successfully creates 3 buttons (since I have 3 agents in the agents list used in the foreach loop) and the buttons work (which is why the Debug.Log code was added). However, none of the things I added (such as the Labels) appear on clicking the button. What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about unity that much. but there doesnt seem to be an event for the click.
seems to be your only effecting the gui layout without calling and event.
If you need to make labels apear or change there layout when a button is clicked i would suggest.

1. 1st i would create a new function that contained the layout of your labels, this should be in a gui class but in unity i understand that you simply attach scripts to wizard created objects?
2. 2nd i would then create an event handler for your button, so say button 1?  public button1_onClick(event handler properties go hear)
3. last i would simply call the label layout method inside of the event handler method
   public button1_onclick(){
      Label1layout();
   }

Something like this.  Though not sure this is what you mean.
Hope this gives you a rough idea into the process of events and how to use them

Answer (score 0):

In unity gui the code for the button click is enclosed in the `if` statement for the button.

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Button Text"))
{ 
    // code for click event goes here
}
```

this code only gets called for the frame in which the button is pressed so, in your example above, you are only displaying the details for the agent you clicked for 1 frame.

you need to change it to something like

```
if (GUILayout.Button(agent.shortName))
{
    agent.selected = true;
}

if(agent.selected)
{
    Debug.Log("clicked" + agent.shortName);
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();
    GUILayout.Label("Health: "+agent.Health +"/"+agent.MaximumHealth);
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();
    GUILayout.Label("Thoughts: nothing");
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    /*if (agent.hasFlag)
    { //TODO: Add this function to agent
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        GUILayout.Label("Has the flag");        
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
    }*/
}
```

if you only want to show the info while the button is held down you can change the `GUILayout.Button` to `GUILayout.RepeatButton` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `OnGUI` function is called every frame, like `Update`. This means that your label only gets drawn during that on `OnGUI` call that happens when the  button is clicked.